# Nuxt.js: How to include an asynchronous script in the nuxt.config.js file?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have the following script to load any Google Font for my site asynchronously:

```
<!-- Load Google Fonts Asynchronously -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.18/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
  WebFont.load({google:{families:['IBM+Plex+Sans']}});
</script>
<!-- End Load Google Fonts Asynchronously -->
```

Usually, in my `Vue.js` application I would just add this to the head of `index.html` inside the `/public` directory, however, I was wondering how I would add this globally to the head section for my `nuxt.js` SSR application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the example from the nuxt doc with Google Analytics to import and execute an external lib: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/google-analytics/

---

But another easier way is to use the [webfontloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webfontloader):

1/ Install `webfontloader` with npm or yarn

```
npm install webfontloader --save
```

2/ Create a custom plugin

```
// plugins/webfont.js

const WebFont = require('webfontloader');

WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: ['IBM+Plex+Sans']
  }
});
```

3/ Enable your filter

```
// nuxt.config.js:

plugins: [
  {src: '~plugins/webfont.js', ssr: false}
],
```

The plugin will be execute only on client-side rendering, due to `ssr: false` option.